# Expanding of UMat into data, step and the offset

Tags: opencv, opencl, mat

while i was looking into the OpenCV code of ORB I encountered following part:

```
return hr_ker.args(ocl::KernelArg::ReadOnlyNoSize(imgbuf),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrReadOnly(layerinfo),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrReadOnly(keypoints),
            ocl::KernelArg::PtrWriteOnly(responses),
            nkeypoints).run(1, globalSize, 0, true);
```

This part loads the kernel arguments an runs the kernel (ORB_HarrisResponses). the UMat imgbuf expands to the following parameters (found this statement on a question on stakoverflow)

```
         uchar* data, int step, int offset,
```

Kernel:

```
ORB_HarrisResponses(__global const uchar* imgbuf, int imgstep, int imgoffset0,
                __global const int* layerinfo, __global const int* keypoints,
                __global float* responses, int nkeypoints, int blockSize, float scale_sq_sq, float HARRIS_K )
```

{}

My question is, how can i acces these values in my code (Host Code). I´m looking for something like :

```
Umat test
test.data //Mat correspondant
test.step
```